# Issue with logical operator for Strings

Tags: java, string, while-loop, logical-operators

I am trying to write a loop to prompt user input until either `"AM"` or `"PM"` is entered (case insensitive). However, the following code brings me to an infinite loop even when `"AM"` or `"PM"` is being entered. `console` is my scanner class variable.

```
String AMPM = "";
do {
    System.out.println("Enter AM or PM: ");
    AMPM = console.next();
} while (!AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") || !AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("PM"));
```

I have tried the to remove the the second `!` as such and it only breaks the loop for `"AM"`.

```
!AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") || AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("PM")
```

What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: You should use `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") && !AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("PM")
```

(as @saka1029deleted suggested)
or:

```
!( AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") || AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("PM") )
```

### Explanation

|  | AM | PM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| !AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") | false | true |
| !AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("PM") | true | false |
| !AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") && !AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("PM") | false | false |

|  | AM | PM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") | true | false |
| AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("PM") | false | true |
| AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") || AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("PM") | true | true |
| !( AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("AM") || AMPM.equalsIgnoreCase("PM") ) | false | false |

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
do { … }
while (
    !
    List
    .of( "AM" , "PM" )
    .contains( input.toUpperCase() )
)
```

## Details

The Answer by hata seems correct.

An alternative approach that I find easier to read involves the use of streams. Make a stream of the target values. Then ask if any of those match your input.

```
boolean expectedInput = List.of( "AM" , "PM" ).stream().anyMatch( target -> target. equalsIgnoreCase( input ) ) ;
```

An even simpler alternative asks a list if it contains a copy of the input converted to uppercase.

```
boolean expectedInput = List.of( "AM" , "PM" ).contains( input.toUpperCase() ) ;
```